# Is there a way to speed up the writing process in the database?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to read the data from multiple csv files and write them in a mysql database. I'm using spring batch, is there a way to tune up the speed?

I'm using MultiResourceItemReader to read csv files and using JdbcBatchItemWriter to write the data to the database.

```
@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(
            new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
    writer.setSql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)");
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return writer;
}
```

I want my application to write around 500K data in few seconds or minutes, Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to start is to use a [Multithreaded step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep), where each chunk is processed by a separate thread. This can speed up your batch job.

You can also try to use the partitioning technique with the `MultiResourcePartitioner`. With this partitioner, a partition is created for each file and those partitions are processed in parallel either locally with multiple threads or remotely with multiples workers.I suggest you start locally with the `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler`. While a thread is reading/processing one file, another thread could be writing data of another file to the database, and this should speed up things. You can find a code example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#partitioning-sample).

You can also watch the [High Performance Batch Processing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6IPlfm7N6w) talk where all scaling techniques are presented in details with code examples.

Hope this helps.